# conditional formatting from different column

Tags: gridview, extjs, formatting, ext.net

As shown in ext.net examples, [this](http://examples1.ext.net/#/GridPanel/ArrayGrid/Simple/) is code to format a column-entry

```
var template = '<span style="color:{0};">{1}</span>';

var change = function (value) {
   return String.format(template, (value > 0) ? "green" : "red", value);
};
```

now my question is, i want to format column company likewise.

```
var company = function(value) {
   return String.format(template, (record.data.change > 0) ? "green" : "red", value);
};
```

this did not work as record will not be given to the function, also i failed to pass a parameter to Fn called on renderer

```
var company = function(value, change) {
   return String.format(template, (change > 0) ? "green" : "red", value);
};
```

i could also imagine a workaround with jquery, but that's just a whole bunch of work and selectors. and as i am quite new to ext.net / extjs i am sure i overlooked something

P.S. yes i am using the older version of ext.net, thus the link is to examples1.ext.net ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always take a look at the ExtJS API. Here you would looking for **[Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer)**

The renderer arguments are

- **value** : *Object*
  The data value for the current cell
- **metaData** : *Object*
  A collection of metadata about the current cell; can be used or modified by the renderer. Recognized properties are: tdCls, tdAttr, and style.
- **record** : *Ext.data.Model*
  The record for the current row
- **rowIndex** : *Number*
  The index of the current row
- **colIndex** : *Number*
  The index of the current column
- **store** : *Ext.data.Store*
  The data store
- **view** : *Ext.view.View*
  The current view

so I guess this should work for you

```
var company = function(value, meta, record) {
   return String.format(template, (record.data.change > 0) ? "green" : "red", value);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd argument to the renderer is the record. The first is the value, the second is metadata about the cell: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column-cfg-renderer

Comment: Same answer at the same time ;) +1

Comment: Creepy ;) +1 to you as well.